# PyCharm expected type warning

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, numpy-ndarray

My code contains the following lines:

```
import numpy as np
T = 1.00
tlist = np.linspace(0, T, 1000)
```

When using tlist as an input to a function, I get the following warning:
[Expected type 'Type[ndarray]', got 'Union[ndarray, tuple[ndarray, Optional[float]]]' instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiu0g.png)

Attempting to fix this problem by specifying the type
`tlist : np.ndarray = np.linspace(0, T, 1000)`
results in this:
[Expected type 'Type[ndarray]', got 'Union[ndarray, ndarray]' instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoH8v.png)

Is there any way to fix this problem without disabling the type inspection?

Comment: As an input to _what_ function?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Your posted code does not generate any warnings in my computer

Comment: @AKX The krotov.objective.mesolve and krotov.optimize_pulses functions. tlist is not altered/used as an input to other functions before calling these two.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Interesting. Is the type shown when your mouse hovers over the variable different than mine? It could be that the type inspection is disabled on your version but it will also expect a strange type like in my case.

Comment: @Yuval Marcus  you have posted 3 lines of code. I have copy pasted this exact 3 lines of code and upon execution they don't display any warning. You are just basically using linspace to create an equally spaced array of 1000 elements between 0 and 1. No warnings here.  About your answer to AKX we have no idea what the "krotov.objective.mesolve and krotov.optimize_pulses functions" are unless you post a minimal reproducible version of the code that shows the warning you are talking about

Comment: Hi there Yuval. These problems sometimes come up for me also in PyCharm. Sometimes changing my Python Interpreter can help. Also, it is worth going to File --> Invalidate caches to rebuild the project cache and restart the IDE. That may help.

Comment: @YuvalMarcus There is no `krotov.objective.mesolve` function. There is (apparently) a `krotov.Objective` class with a `mesolve` method – but as Sembei Norimaki said, you will need to show the _actual code_ and the _actual line_ that shows you the warning. Those three lines you've shown us so far absolutely raise no warnings whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

if your function definition looks like this:

```
def my_function(tlist):
```

You can modify it to include the type annotation for the input parameter tlist like this:

```
from typing import Union
import numpy as np
def my_function(tlist: Union[np.ndarray, tuple[np.ndarray, float]]):
```

Comment: That's good to know, but I'm using functions from a package that I didn't write (krotov.objective.mesolve and krotov.optimize_pulses) so editing them is not an option.